# Tabview is not displayed at the bottom

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a `TabView` but although I try to insert it at the bottom, it continues to be displayed at the top

```
 <xct:TabView TabStripPlacement="Bottom" IsSwipeEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="White">
            <xct:TabViewItem 
                    x:Name="Home"
                    Text="Home"
                    TextColorSelected="Black"
                    TextColor="Gray"
                    Icon="IC003.png">
            </xct:TabViewItem>
    
            <xct:TabViewItem 
                    x:Name="Diario"
                    Text="Diario"
                    TextColorSelected="Black"
                    TextColor="Gray"
                    Icon="Smile.png">
            </xct:TabViewItem>
        </xct:TabView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabStripPlacement` is used to set the tab at bottom or top. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

We could put the tabview inside the layout like StackLayout, Grid and so on. But without layous, it still works. We just need to give some contents of the items.

```
 <xct:TabView
        BackgroundColor="White"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False"
        TabStripHeight="60"
        TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <xct:TabViewItem
            x:Name="Home"
            Icon="IC003.png"
            Text="Home"
            TextColor="Gray"
            TextColorSelected="Black">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="TabContent1"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </xct:TabViewItem>

        <xct:TabViewItem
            x:Name="Diario"
            Icon="Smile.png"
            Text="Diario"
            TextColor="Gray"
            TextColorSelected="Black">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="TabContent2"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </xct:TabViewItem>
    </xct:TabView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it inside a Grid like this:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="*, Auto">
    <!-- insert stuff here -->
    <xct:TabView Grid.Row="2" TabStripPlacement="Bottom" IsSwipeEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="White">
</Grid>
```

I think that the `TabStripPlacement` does not mean that it will be placed on the bottom of the outer element.